# Nginx - serving static files

Tags: nginx, alias, static-content

What am I doing wrong here?

This works:

```
location / {
    alias /var/www/static/;
    try_files $uri index.html =404;
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
location /hello {
    alias /var/www/static/;
    try_files $uri index.html =404;
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
[error] 14428#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/bundle.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I know that Nginx is looking for bundle.js from the wrong directory. It should be located in the /var/www/static/ folder.

I can fix that by adding

```
root /var/www/static/
```

in the beginning of my config but then if I add another location the same problem re-emerges.

```
location /world {
    alias /var/www/another/;
    try_files $uri index.html =404;
}
```

Error:

```
[error] 14827#0: *1 open() "/var/www/static/bundle2.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

bundle2.js should be in the /var/www/another/ folder but because I defined root as /var/www/static/ Nginx is looking for bundle2.js from the wrong folder.

Here is the whole config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/static/;

    location /hello {
        alias /var/www/static/;
        try_files $uri index.html =404;
    }

    location /world {
        alias /var/www/another/;
        try_files $uri index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the file requested inside your html file? 
If you request it with a slash in the beginning (`<script src="/bundles.js"></script>`) it is root-relative, leading nginx to look for the file in the website's root directory, which with your first config was the default directory. With the second config nginx looked it up under "/var/www/static"
If your .js is called by `<script src="bundles.js"></script>` (relative path) it should work.